# How to compare user defined variable to string literal

Tags: sh

I'm trying to write a script to allow users to input a filename and display either the number of lines, words, characters, or all three, that are in the file depending on whether the user enters `'l'` (lines), `'w'` (words), `'c'` (characters), or `'a'` (all).

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                         

# Prompt for filename                                                                                                             
read -p 'Enter the file name: ' filename

# Prompt which of lines, words, or chars to display                                                                               
read -p 'Count lines, words, characters, or all three (l, w, c, a)? ' display
while [ $display -ne "l" -o $display -ne "w" -o $display -ne "c" -o $display -ne "a" ]
do
    echo "Invalid option"
    read -p 'Count lines, words, characters, or all three (l, w, c, a)? ' display
done

# Display to stdout number of lines, words, or chars                                                                              
set `wc $filename`
if [ $display -eq "l" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $1 lines."
elif [ $display -eq "w" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $2 words."
elif [ $display -eq "c" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $3 characters."
else
    echo "File '$4' contains $1 lines, $2 words, and $3 characters."
fi
```

If I run the script and supply a file called `trial.txt` and choose option `w`, I getting the output:

```
./icount: 11: [: Illegal number: w
./icount: 19: [: Illegal number: w
./icount: 22: [: Illegal number: w
./icount: 25: [: Illegal number: w
File 'trial.txt' contains 3 lines, 19 words, and 154 characters.
```

Can someone help me interpret this error?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `-eq` and `-ne` are integer comparison operators. You have to use `=` and `!=` when comparing strings.

Comment: True. But even with that correction your script fails if the user gives an empty input, the input `hi there`, or in most cases the input `*`. For bonus points, use quoting or (usually better in ksh/bash/etc) `[[` to fix those also.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should use `AND conditions` in while loop

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                         

# Prompt for filename                                                                                                             
read -p 'Enter the file name: ' filename

# Prompt which of lines, words, or chars to display                                                                               
read -p 'Count lines, words, characters, or all three (l, w, c, a)? ' display
while [ "$display" != "l" -a "$display" !=  "w" -a "$display" != "c" -a "$display" != "a" ]
do
    echo "Invalid option"
    read -p 'Count lines, words, characters, or all three (l, w, c, a)? ' display
done

# Display to stdout number of lines, words, or chars                                                                              

set `wc $filename`
if [ $display == "l" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $1 lines."
elif [ $display == "w" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $2 words."
elif [ $display == "c" ]
then
    echo "File '$4' contains $3 characters."
else
    echo "File '$4' contains $1 lines, $2 words, and $3 characters."
fi
```